# How to draw a square when a button is pressed in java

Tags: java, swing, drawing, paintcomponent, repaint

I am writing a java program where you input a length and you input a width of a rectangle and it outputs the perimeter and area. But now, I want to **draw** the figure as well. But I don't know how to draw it when the button is pressed. Should it look like this?:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawRect(10, 10, 80, 30);      
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    paintComponent();
}
```

Because when I do that it gives me an error saying:

```
method paintComponent in class Rectangles cannot be applied to given types;
required: Graphics
found: no arguments
```

So I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you shouldn't call `paintComponent` directly. That method will be called automatically anyway, so the square would be drawn before you click.

You could use a boolean flag to indicate that you clicked the button and call `repaint()` to post a repaint request:

```
boolean clicked = false;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (clicked) {
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.drawRect(10, 10, 80, 30);
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    clicked = true;
    repaint();
}
```

Moreover, **never** let a method call itself with exactly the same parameters. This snipped

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    paintComponent(g);
```

will call the same function infinitely often (or until the stack is full).

I think you saw the following somewhere:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
```

That is ok, it will call the paint method of the super class. It probably doesn't do anything, so leaving it out shouldn't harm (but neither does keeping it).

Comment: Thanks but when I do that, it gives me a `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. I don't know why.

Comment: @DLJ I didn't make it explicit, but I removed the call to `paintComponent(g);` from `paintComponent`. You should do the same :) (or have it as `super.paintComponent(g)`)

Comment: @DLJ : Try to override [getPreferredSize()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize()) and make it return some valid `Dimension` object, just like you overriding `paintComponent(...)` method, e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17573406/1057230)